# flow string is incompatible with string literal?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to annotate a custom event emitter and restrict the event names to specific strings.  For this example though I'll just use one event name:

```
class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
  on(event: 'foo', listener: Function): this {
    return super.on(event, listener);
  }
}
```

Flow doesn't like this though and complains that `'foo'` is not compatible with `string`??

```
 24: class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^ MyEmitter. Cannot extend
 24: class MyEmitter extends EventEmitter {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ EventEmitter
  Property `on` is incompatible:
           v-------------------------------------------
     25:   on(event: 'foo', listener: Function): this {
     26:     return super.on(event, listener);
     27:   }
           ^ function. This type is incompatible with
    660:   on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ function type. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_15c48d81/node.js:660
      The first parameter is incompatible:
         25:   on(event: 'foo', listener: Function): this {
                         ^^^^^ string literal `foo`. Expected string literal `foo`
        660:   on(event: string, listener: Function): this;
                         ^^^^^^ string. See lib: /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_15c48d81/node.js:660
```

[edit]

standalone example on [tryflow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rwHYAoBmiAXNBAC4BOAllgOYCUK60Avqq6qJDAEJjnQBTAB6kBWACYwESNBmz4i0AOQAjPkoayWbIA):

```
class Foo {
  on(foo: string) {
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  on(foo: 'bar') {
  }
}
```

Comment: This question should be tagged `java` not `javascript`

Comment: @Ahmad, no... `flowtype` is a JavaScript typechecker. It has nothing whatsoever to do with Java. This also isn't Java syntax.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you could define an interface with restriction.  [Example](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rwHYAoBmiAXNBAC4BOAllgOYCUK60Avqq6taQKbl5jBdoASQBCYcowzZ8RaAHIARuLl1iAN3iUAJgG42qVKEgwxErgA9uWLTARJKAWwAOILg65ZSMUeMmZcBPDEZFS0DGgYrOzA2GTQSuTEPhIAvNBYXADu0KY4dHoJAHTSisr50AD0FQDyANKoRSWBKjqVFQCi5OTw5EA)

Comment: @AlekseyL. - can you make that an answer?  I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface with restriction:

```
class Foo {
  on(foo: string) {
  }
}

interface IBar {
  on(foo: 'bar'): void;
}

class Bar extends Foo implements IBar {
  on(foo: string) {
  }
}

const bar: IBar = new Bar();
bar.on('bar'); //OK
bar.on('foo'); //Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Bar`'s `on` function is overriding `Foo`s, the type of `foo` in the subclass's method needs to be a subtype of the corresponding type in the superclass's method. While `'bar'` is a `string`, all `string` are not `'bar'`.

For example, these will compile fine:

```
class Baz {
  on(foo: string|number) {
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  on(foo: string|'bar') {
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, what you're looking for is not possible in Flow since it has contravariant inputs. The docs have an [example](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-more-specific-inputs-bad) to that very effect. I suppose the workaround is to use a wrapper function that simply calls the overloaded version since using generics isn't possible here.

While unrelated, it's interesting to note that support for covariant inputs (what you're looking for) are not common. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_method_argument_type) Eiffel is the unique "mainstream" language that supports it.

Comment: So how do I actually restrict the valid arguments in the overriding method?  `string|'bar' === string`, making the whole thing pointless

Comment: I'm not entirely certain you can (without a new function that just calls the superclass version). See https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/subtypes/#toc-subtypes-of-functions and the next page which says "All of this is why Flow has contravariant inputs (accepts less specific types to be passed in), and covariant outputs (allows more specific types to be returned)", especially https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/variance/#toc-more-specific-inputs-bad.

Comment: @MarkKahn I've edited the details above into my answer and added something interesting I ran across. The linked wikipedia article is a good read.